# Sort order of the user filter is surprising to me

Tags: bug, status-completed, users, sorting, users-page

When filling in the "Type to Find Users", it seems to sort by exact match and then by reputation when I am on the reputation tab.

For example, please consider the following search results:

[image: user search results for "test" show many low-rep users with that exact username, followed by higher-rep users whose usernames contain "test" as a substring]

This threw me off since I thought that the sort order is reputation. I guess this often might give people what they want, but when picking a popular name it shows a lot of 0 rep users. Maybe adding a filter for low rep to the exact match might give more expected results, or just sorting on rep?

Comment: **SEVEN** years later, I was about to report the same bug, then I saw this question. Since I already have a screen at hand, I will edit to add it for further reference.

Comment: @SPArcheon (almost) **ELEVEN** by now. ;-)

Answer (score 6):

So, this is an odd one, I'm not sure what the issue truly was when this was first reported, but we've identified a bug introduced by a refactoring in a common database query used by all of the "/users" tabs: there was a mismatch in the intended logic that would stop the actual ordering (e.g.: higher reputation first on the reputation tab) from happening once a user search was performed. This issue has been fixed, and the ordering in those tabs should now be working again.

Unfortunately we've discussed internally, and won't be changing the "Exact matches first" behavior just yet, so that will still happen at least for the near future.

We recognize that both that search and those tabs could be more user friendly, and it's in our roadmap to modernize that whole experience.

Apologies for the huge delay, and I hope this fix will at least improve your lives until more changes come. Thank you for reporting!