# Searching on users page and sorting by reputation

Tags: discussion, user-accounts, sorting

So I feel like this is either a dumb question or a dupe, but here we go...

If I go to the "Users" page on a site and search, and then sort by all-time reputation (as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=all&search=hello+world)), I get very confusing results:

[image: User reputation sorting]

I don't understand how these are sorted. There is one person with over 1K rep, and they are not (in any way that I can see) placed above the person with 1 or 19.  How are these sorted?

Comment: You are correct, it looks broken. You can **[see a working result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kyLD4.jpg)** here, of [**some*** of the list, correctly sorted](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/alltime/stackoverflow?search=hello+world). * users with less than 200 reputation are not tracked in the leagues

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of [Sort Order on the User Filter is Surprising To Me](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/99912/289905) or [Searching for some users on SO returns a list sorted by incorrect order](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/347964/289905). _“Users with the same name are sorted by userid not reputation.”_ — [DavidPostill, May 15 at 18:39](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/347964/289905#comment1164293_347964).